# Invalid URI after closing calling Activity

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask, uri, media

I have an Activity with multiple ImageViews showing images retrieved by calling a camera intent. On onActivityResult I store the image Uri returned for later background processing.

The thing is: once I finish the calling activity, some of my stored URIs (passed to an AsyncTask) are invalid and when I try to load them (i.e. with Glide), raise a NullPointerException.

I can't keep the Activity running during the background processing, which takes some time and gives users a bad experience.

I've tried other methods when acquiring the images thinking the read permission availability and life cycle would have to do with the calling method (created myself a file in the file system and passed it to the camera intent, for example), but none of this worked.

I've tried with different devices and different Android version and the issue persists, is it and implicit pattern of Android?

Has any of you experienced this problem?

Tha camera and gallery intent calls:

```
    public static void getCameraImage(Activity activity) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Codes.CAMERA_IMAGE);
    }
}

public static void getGalleryImage(Activity activity){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, Codes.GALLERY_IMAGE);
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
            (requestCode == Codes.CAMERA_IMAGE || requestCode == Codes.GALLERY_IMAGE)) {

        Uri uri = intent.getData();

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(uri)
                .fitCenter()
                .centerCrop()
                .into((ImageView) findViewById(myImageViewId));

        savedUri = uri;            
    }
}
```

AsyncTask call:

```
//PostImages extends AsyncTask
PostImages post = new PostVehicleImages(savedUri);
post.execute();
finish()
```

Async task execution:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    callService(savedUri);

    return null;
}

private void callService(Uri savedUri) {

    Bitmap image = null;
    try{
        image = Glide.with(App.getAppContext())
                .load(savedUri) //<----- crashes here
                .asBitmap()
                .into(640, 640)
                .get();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Retrofit retrofit = ServiceBuilder.getBuilder();

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), byteArray);
    VehicleService service = retrofit.create(VehicleService.class);

    Call<Void> call = service.sendImage(credentials, vehicleID, index, file);

    try {
        call.execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I call PostImages after I validate the Uri and the user press a button (Send). The AsyncTask receives the Uri, loads it and then sends it to a webserver, thus the AsyncTask.

I simplified a little (when I call the AsyncTask I pass  4 URIs to it), sometimes one or two are sent correctly, but never all of them are successful, it raises a NullPointerException when loading the bitmap from the Uri at the statement `.load(savedUri)`.

I've tried using the pointed file path, but apparently it depends heavily on SDK version / device, and also wields problems.

Comment: At what point do you call the `PostImages` code you have there and what exactly is the tasks purpose?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Edited for clarification (at the bottom).

Comment: So it is not the `Uri` itself that is null but maybe the location the `Uri` points to is no longer valid? You might want to add the code where you are loading the bitmap along with the stack trace of the error that is occurring.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Added the call as requested.